# How to solve $e^{f(x)} + a f(x) + bx = 0$

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

How should determine solutions to equations of this form? 
$$e^{-f(x)} + b f(x) = ax$$
Here $f(x)>0$ is real valued. Also $a>0$, $b>0$.

Comment: I guess my question might be equivalent to "How to efficiently compute the inverse of $$y \mapsto e^{-y}+by $$" so maybe it belongs elsewhere?

Comment: Probably you should explain why the usual methods (such as Newton's iteration, etc) for numerical solution of equations are inadequate for your purposes. Otherwise, I think this question is more suitable for math.stackexchange.com (see Help Center for more information).

Comment: Appreciate the redirect Boris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = W(-\exp(-ax/b)/b) + ax/b$
where W is one of the branches of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).